# jQuery prevent animation trigger if another is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

I have some simple fade functions that trigger fade outs/ins of divs. However if you spam clicking the buttons they all start running and looks awful. What I would like is to only trigger the function if none are currently running.

```
$('.a').click(function(){
  $('#about, #contact').fadeOut(500);
  $('#welcome').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
})
$('.b').click(function(){
  $('#welcome, #contact').fadeOut(500);
  $('#about').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
})
$('.c').click(function(){
  $('#about, #welcome').fadeOut(500);
  $('#contact').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store status of fading of elements in variable and before fading check status. In this case i added `running` variable.

```js
var running = false;
$('.a').click(function(){
  if (!running){
    running = true;
    $('#about, #contact').fadeOut(500);
    $('#welcome').delay(500).fadeIn(500, function(){
      running = false;
    });
  }
})
$('.b').click(function(){
  if (!running){
    running = true;
    $('#welcome, #contact').fadeOut(500);
    $('#about').delay(500).fadeIn(500, function(){
      running = false;
    });
  }
})
$('.c').click(function(){
  if (!running){
    running = true;
    $('#about, #welcome').fadeOut(500);
    $('#contact').delay(500).fadeIn(500, function(){
      running = false;
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">aaa</div>
<div class="b">bbb</div>
<div class="c">ccc</div>
<div id="welcome">welcome</div>
<div id="about">about</div>
<div id="contact">contact</div>
```

Also you can simplify your code as shown in bottom

```js
var running = false;
$('.button').find('.a, .b, .c').click(function(){
  if (!running){
    running = true;
    var dataChild = $(this).data("child");
    $(".child *:not(#"+dataChild+")").fadeOut(500);
    $("#"+dataChild).delay(500).fadeIn(500, function(){
      running = false;
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <div class="a" data-child="welcome">aaa</div>
  <div class="b" data-child="about">bbb</div>
  <div class="c" data-child="contact">ccc</div>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <div id="welcome">welcome</div>
  <div id="about">about</div>
  <div id="contact">contact</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, and thank you for showing me a better way to write it!